# when to use an apostrophe showing possession and not use one

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a story about a family.named Litchford. So if I say the Litchfords were farmers do I need an apostrophe. How about We saw with Pleasant Litchfords committment to education... The Litchfords and Depps had been slave families from Virginia. Does this need an apostrophe?

Comment: "So if I say the Litchfords were farmers do I need an apostrophe"  - but that's not a possessive, is it?

Answer (score 5):

There are two reasons for putting an s at the end of Litchford:

- if it's a plural: you are talking about more than one member of the Litchford family
- if it's a possessive: you are talking about something that a member of the Litchford owns, or some property of characteristic of them.

If it's a plural, an apostrophe is not required. If it's a possessive, an apostrophe is required before the s. If it's a plural **and** a possessive, the apostrophe goes after the s.

> The Litchfords were farmers -*plural, no apostrophe*
>   Pleasant Litchford's commmitment to education - *possessive- apostrophe before s*
>   the Litchfords' commitment to education - *possessive plural- apostrophe after s*